# Upstart node.js mysql connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, upstart, forever

I am new to node.js so in an attempt to learn it I tried to run this example 
http://markshust.com/2013/11/07/creating-nodejs-server-client-socket-io-mysql

It has no problems and everything is working fine. But then I wanted to run this server through forever and upstart, and a strange problem occured. When I first reboot the system, upstart runs the server fine, but the server script doesn't list mysql entries. But when I kill the server and forever starts it up again, everything works fine. Could you help me with this? Here is my upstart conf.

```
#!upstart

description "Forever and Node.js"

start on (starting mysql)
stop on shutdown

expect fork

env NODE_BIN_DIR="***"
env NODE_PATH="***"
env APPLICATION_DIRECTORY="***"
env APPLICATION_START="***"
env LOG="***"

script
        PATH=$NODE_BIN_DIR:$PATH

        exec forever --sourceDir $APPLICATION_DIRECTORY -a -l $LOG --minUptime 5000 --    spinSleepTime 2000 start $APPLICATION_START
end script

pre-stop script
        PATH=$NODE_BIN_DIR:$PATH
        exec forever stop $APPLICATION_START >> $LOG
end script
```

Comment: Is the mysql server accepting connections the moment your script starts?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
start on (starting mysql)
```

with

```
start on (started mysql)
```

fixed the problem. Thank you all for this priceless community.